# Error when upgrading ThingsBoard CE from 3.4.4 to 3.5.0

Tags: upgrade, thingsboard, thingsboard-gateway

```html
Starting upgrade                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Pulling tboard (thingsboard/tb-postgres:3.5.1)...                                                                                                                                                                  
3.5.1: Pulling from thingsboard/tb-postgres                                                                                                                                                                        
9e3ea8720c6d: Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                                        
066524c96da2: Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                                        
3f7d6085deb3: Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                                        
4cede6cde454: Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                                        
cfeceda93bbe: Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                                        
Digest: sha256:dbb1b4f65a452b717c37d7aaf3b98918052f5f382f7f20a5aabb63d996b67540                                                                                                                                    
Status: Downloaded newer image for thingsboard/tb-postgres:3.5.1                                                                                                                                                   
Starting Postgresql...                                                                                                                                                                                             
pg_ctl: another server might be running; trying to start server anyway                                                                                                                                             
waiting for server to start....2023-08-01 05:13:16.892 UTC [12] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.15 (Debian 12.15-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit       
2023-08-01 05:13:16.893 UTC [12] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432                                                                                                                            
2023-08-01 05:13:16.893 UTC [12] LOG:  could not bind IPv6 address "::1": Cannot assign requested address                                                                                                          
2023-08-01 05:13:16.893 UTC [12] HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.                                                                                  
2023-08-01 05:13:16.912 UTC [12] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"                                                                                                                
2023-08-01 05:13:16.958 UTC [13] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2023-08-01 04:23:22 UTC                                                                                                   
2023-08-01 05:13:17.132 UTC [13] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress                                                                                                  
2023-08-01 05:13:17.147 UTC [13] LOG:  redo starts at 0/182BBE0                                                                                                                                                    
2023-08-01 05:13:17.147 UTC [13] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/182BC18: wanted 24, got 0                                                                                                                        
2023-08-01 05:13:17.147 UTC [13] LOG:  redo done at 0/182BBE0                                                                                                                                                      
2023-08-01 05:13:17.229 UTC [12] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections                                                                                                                              
 done                                                                                                                                                                                                              
server started                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Postgresql is ready                                                                                                                                                                                                
Starting ThingsBoard upgrade ...                                                                                                                                                                                   
  __    _      _                              __                               _                                                                                                                           
 /_  _/   / /    ()   __    __ _   __   / _ )  __   __ _   __  __/ /                                                                                                                           
  / /     / _ \  / /   / _ \  / _ `/  / _/  / _  | / _ \ / _ `/  / _/ / __  /                                                                                                                            
 / /     / / / / / /   / / / / / // /  (_  )  / // / / // // // /  / /    / // /                                                                                                                             
//     // // //   // //  \_, /  /_/  /__/  \_/ \_,/  //     \,/                                                                                                                              
                              /__/                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 ===================================================                                                                                                                                                               
 :: ThingsBoard ::       (v3.5.1)                                                                                                                                                                                  
 ===================================================                                                                                                                                                               
Starting ThingsBoard Upgrade from version 3.4.4 ...
Clearing cache to upgrade from version 3.4.4 to 3.5.0
Clearing cache [relations]
Clearing cache [deviceCredentials]
Clearing cache [devices]                            
Clearing cache [sessions]                           
Clearing cache [assets]                             
Clearing cache [entityViews]
Clearing cache [claimDevices]
Clearing cache [securitySettings]
Clearing cache [tenantProfiles]
Clearing cache [tenants]                            
Clearing cache [tenantsExist]
Clearing cache [deviceProfiles]
Clearing cache [assetProfiles]
Clearing cache [notificationSettings]
Clearing cache [sentNotifications]
Clearing cache [attributes]
Clearing cache [userSessionsInvalidation]
Clearing cache [otaPackages]
Clearing cache [otaPackagesData]
Clearing cache [edges]                              
Clearing cache [repositorySettings]
Clearing cache [autoCommitSettings]
Clearing cache [twoFaVerificationCodes]
Clearing cache [versionControlTask]
Clearing cache [userSettings]
Clearing cache [dashboardTitles]
Clearing cache [entityCount]
Upgrading ThingsBoard from version 3.4.4 to 3.5.0 ...
Updating schema ...                                 
Failed updating schema!!!
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: canceling statement due to user request
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2676)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2366)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:356)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:496)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:413)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:333)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:319)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:295)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:290)
        at org.thingsboard.server.service.install.SqlDatabaseUpgradeService.loadSql(SqlDatabaseUpgradeService.java:743)
        at org.thingsboard.server.service.install.SqlDatabaseUpgradeService.upgradeDatabase(SqlDatabaseUpgradeService.java:685)
        at org.thingsboard.server.install.ThingsboardInstallService.performInstall(ThingsboardInstallService.java:251)
        at org.thingsboard.server.ThingsboardInstallApplication.main(ThingsboardInstallApplication.java:49)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)                                                                                                                                              
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.main(PropertiesLauncher.java:467)
Creating default notification configs for system admin
Unexpected error during ThingsBoard installation!
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:259)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:145)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy247.countByTenantId(Unknown Source)
        at org.thingsboard.server.dao.sql.notification.JpaNotificationTargetDao.countByTenantId(JpaNotificationTargetDao.java:76)
        at org.thingsboard.server.dao.sql.notification.JpaNotificationTargetDao$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$419ea42e.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:89)
        at org.thingsboard.server.dao.aspect.SqlDaoCallsAspect.handleSqlCall(SqlDaoCallsAspect.java:158)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:634)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:624)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:72)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
        at org.thingsboard.server.dao.sql.notification.JpaNotificationTargetDao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$17082908.countByTenantId(<generated>)
        at org.thingsboard.server.dao.notification.DefaultNotificationTargetService.countNotificationTargetsByTenantId(DefaultNotificationTargetService.java:197)
        at org.thingsboard.server.service.install.DefaultSystemDataLoaderService.createDefaultNotificationConfigs(DefaultSystemDataLoaderService.java:691)
        at org.thingsboard.server.install.ThingsboardInstallService.performInstall(ThingsboardInstallService.java:253)
        at org.thingsboard.server.ThingsboardInstallApplication.main(ThingsboardInstallApplication.java:49)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.main(PropertiesLauncher.java:467)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:103)
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:37)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:67)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2322)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2075)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2037)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:956)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:357)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2868)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2850)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2682)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2677)
        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:540)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:218)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1459)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1649)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1617)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1665)
        at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getSingleResult(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:111)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:410)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy331.getSingleResult(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:198)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:90)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:156)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:144)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:160)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:139)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:81)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
        ... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "notification_target" does not exist
  Position: 48                                      
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2676)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2366)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:356)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:496)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:413)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:190)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:134)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57)
        ... 80 common frames omitted
Unexpected error during ThingsBoard installation!
waiting for server to shut down....2023-08-01 08:13:54.250 UTC [12] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2023-08-01 08:13:54.621 UTC [12] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2023-08-01 08:13:54.626 UTC [12] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 19) exited with exit code 1
2023-08-01 08:13:54.630 UTC [14] LOG:  shutting down 
2023-08-01 08:13:54.710 UTC [12] LOG:  database system is shut down
 done                                               
server stopped                                      
> Starting ThingsBoard-3.5.1
Recreating tboard ... done
```

I have a running things board version 3.4.4 running in docker containers. I want to upgrade to version 3.5.1 The upgrade documentation states that I have to upgrade to 3.5.0 first and then to 3.5.1 I run the upgrade script to version 3.5.0, but I get an error updating the schemas.

I tried to update immediately to 3.5.1 as prescribed in the script, but still an error. Tell me what can be done or where I make mistakes. Here are the logs, this is when trying to upgrade immediately to 3.5.1 When trying to upgrade to 3.5.0 the same errors

Comment: It is difficult to figure out what the reason of described issue, could you give more information?
Logs from install log may be helpful, to get them from docker you can run the following command: `cat /your-log-volume-location/install.log | grep -m 1 -A 100 "Upgrading ThingsBoard from version 3.4.4 to 3.5.0 ..."`.
Do not forget to change **/your-log-volume-location** to your path.

Comment: Here are the update logs